# Connection type of JPA when using Kundera with Cassandra?

Tags: java, jpa, cassandra, database-connection, kundera

Does Java use a `TCP` connection for `JPA` requests to database? For example, if the database server has its `IP address` set to `x.x.x.x:xxxx`, what kind of proxy can handle that connection ? `HTTP` or `TCP` proxy ?

Comment: What do you mean by `proxy`? Do you mean `Network Proxy Server`?

Comment: yes, for example in my application, I only need to define an IP address of that proxy, then the connection will be transfer to the corresponding database servers

Answer (score 3):

A JDBC driver does not necessarily use a network connection.
Hypersonic (HSQL) for example provides different modes of operation

If it is configured as a server it will accept TCP connections and can be accessed with an JDBC-URL like:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://machine/dbname
```

In  embedded mode there is no TCP connection required the URL wouldn't have a server name (or IP)
an URL would look like:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dbname
```

If you use a database server you need to configure the JDBC URL with the machines name (port number if you don't use the default value). There is no need for a proxy, the driver will establish the connection by itself. Btw. HTTP has nothing todo with JDBC.

Comment: thanks, but I use Cassandra, an noSQL db, thus inorder to connect to my application, I used kundera, which is built on top of JPA, inorder to connect to my db, my xml looks like <propertyname="kundera.nodes" value="127.0.0.1" />
<property name="kundera.port" value="9160" /> and there is no way to change the ip value thus I think if I had a proxy to handle that connection, it would be better.

Comment: @Aptos Seems you should follow this tutorial https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes If you have everything installed on one machine localhost (127.0.0.1) should be ok.

Comment: =)) I have up to 4 db servers, 127.0.0.[1,2,3,4] and kundera does not support creating persistent unit dynamically thus using a proxy is an only option for me now..

Comment: @Aptos You could play around with code like http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm But I doubt that this will solve your problem. Perhaps a bit more research is needed to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Oracale pages on JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) and the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html).

How you connect to your database depends on the database and the JDBC driver you use. Some databases like [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) don't use *any* network connection.

Comment: hmmh, I connect to Cassandra database via Kundera method thus there is no JDBC driver here ...

Answer (score 1):

people are confused on this question because JPA != nosql and in fact are quite incompatible.  There are some things the same but JPA is really made for an RDBMS.

All the java clients under the ORM's all use hector, astyanax, etc. etc. which all use thrift which is tcp based.  So you can proxy the tcp if you like and you can generate your own thrift library like astyanax and hector do and create any type of proxy you need.

Dean

PlayOrm Developer